# nginx redirect one URL to another on the same server

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, nginx

so I have an nginx config that responds to one URL, but now it's supposed to redirect from that one URL to another URL (domain name).

What is the best way to redirect to a different domain URL which would still be the same server?

EDIT:
I have tried return 301/302 with all of the flags, and rewrite ^ [new URL], but all of them create a redirect loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit specific, but ill try to put a general rule for a start, we're gonna redirect from `example1.com` to `example2.com`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example1.com;
  return 301 http://example2.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example2.com;
  location / {
    #handle the location
  }
}
```

If you provide more info I would edit this to match your conditions.